# Longest static fire?

Tags: rockets, engines, testing, record, qualification-testing

What is the longest duration for a static fire of a complete rocket stage?

Initially I wanted to ask this for Falcon 9 and Falcon Heavy

I found a 10 second static fire for Falcon Heavy - https://spacenews.com/spacex-conducts-falcon-heavy-static-fire-test/

I am asking because the Starship static fire seems very short

Related question - [Longest continuous burning chemical rocket engine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23361/12102) where [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23363/12102) says:

> In August 1988 an [SSME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-25) (Space Shuttle Main Engine; RS-25) was fired on the ground for 2017 seconds; over 33 minutes.

Comment: From the linked question: In August 1988 an SSME was fired on the ground for 2017 seconds; over 33 minutes.

Comment: Havent noticed that because the guy asked for non static fire tests

Comment: With the existing tags: [testing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing) (96 questions) and [qualification-testing](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qualification-testing)  (9 questions) there was no reason to create a third new tag called `test` so I've replaced it and added the relevant information that (at)OrganicMarble mentioned. Since comments are considered temporary we should try to move relevant information back into the question.

Comment: I had no idea that I can create new tags, can I get this privilege removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The success rate of the Saturn V is attributed, among other factors, to the extensive testing, in particular testing beyond the design parameters. The three stages of the Saturn V had the nominal thrust durations:

- S-1C: 160-170 seconds
- S-II: 360-370 seconds
- S-IVB: 450-500 second (combined)

All stages were subjected to full-duration static firing tests, which would make the S-IVB a good candidate. A full-duration static firing test for the S-IVB used on AS-201 (Saturn 1B configuration) took [452 seconds](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch6.htm). Before that, a test of S-IV-10, used on a Saturn 1, even lasted **[480 seconds](https://www.history.nasa.gov/MHR-5/part-6.htm)**.

The engines were routinely fired beyond their nominal thrust durations, but I have not found any evidence that they did this with the stages too.

In March 2021 a full-duration test of the [SLS](https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/index.html) [lasted 499.6 seconds](https://blogs.nasa.gov/artemis/2021/03/18/green-run-update-full-duration-hot-fire-successfully-completed-on-mar-18/) to take the record.

Hat tip to @IronEagle.

Comment: Excellent find!

Comment: Note: The upcoming final test of the Green Run series (for the SLS) may end up firing the full lower core stage for *up to* 480 seconds.  This is, however, only the core, not including the two boosters.  It also may not run for longer than 452 seconds. https://www.nasa.gov/exploration/systems/sls/proceeding-with-green-run-hot-fire.html 
Currently set to take place on Saturday: https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/nasa-tv-to-air-hot-fire-test-of-rocket-core-stage-for-artemis-moon-missions

Comment: There was a static fire of the S-IV-10 stage for 480 seconds on 1965-01-21: https://www.history.nasa.gov/MHR-5/part-6.htm

Comment: @IronEagle That is a great find, for other reasons as well!

Comment: The second Green Run test completed today, with a runtime of [499.6](https://blogs.nasa.gov/artemis/2021/03/18/green-run-update-full-duration-hot-fire-successfully-completed-on-mar-18/) seconds, I think an update in your answer fits best.

Answer (score 8):

**Longest Static Fire of a rocket engine:**
With you showing interest in the SSME firing (which was probably not attached to a full stage), the Glen Research Center operated a xenon gas engine (0.236 N thrust) continuously from 2003 to 2009 (**[48,000](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/space/sep/gridded-ion-thrusters-next-c/) hours or 5.5 years**).

**Longest Static Fire of a complete solid-fuel stage:**
(See other answer for longest liquid-fuel stage)
In terms of a complete stage, one avenue is solid-fuel stages, as those tend to be tested in full.

- The legendary AJ-260 (an alternative solid-fuel-only Saturn V first stage) had a burn time of [114](http://www.astronautix.com/a/aj-260-2.html) seconds, and three test firings were conducted in [1965-67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerojet).
- The first stage of the Ariane-6 is currently in development, a solid-rocket motor with test firings of [135-140](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P120_(rocket_stage)) seconds.
- The second stage of the [OmegA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmegA) rocket will be the Castor-300, which had a test firing in 2020 which lasted for [139](https://www.space.com/northrop-grumman-omega-rocket-test-fire.html) seconds.
- The second stage of the [Athena I and II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena_(rocket_family)) rockets was the solid-fueled Orbus 21D, with a burn time of [152-156](http://www.b14643.de/Spacerockets/Specials/P&W_ORBUS_motor/index.htm) seconds.  A test firing of duration **[145](http://astronautix.com/t/titan34d.html) seconds** was conducted on [1979-03-16](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a369676.pdf).